# Javascript - Check if there's any false value in nested object

Tags: javascript

I would like to check if this object has any `true` values

```
var test = {"colors":{"blue":false}, "sizes":{"square":true}};
```

I tried with the following code

```
function checkFalse(obj) {
    for (var i in e) {
        for (var j in i) {
            if (i[j] == false) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But it always return `true`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want true values or false ones? Your question title and content contradict each other. Anyway, you want `for( var j in e[i])` and `if(e[i][j])`

Comment: Yep, sorry, I just corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has errors.

```
function checkFalse(obj) {
    for (var i in e) { //This line had an error 
        for (var j in e[i]) { //So did this.
            if (e[i][j] == true) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The question is a little hard for me to understand, unsure if the errors will result in the output you expect, if not, then you need to re-look at your approach v.s. what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for `var i in e` and `e` doesn't exist. Try the following code:

```
    function checkFalse(obj) {
var tempbool = false;
     for (var i in obj) {
 for (var j in i) {
 if (i[j] == true) tempbool = true;
 } 
} 
return tempbool; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are doing wrong. This will return true if you have true at least once. You should do as follows:

```
function checkFalse(obj) {
    for (var i in obj) { 
        for (var j in obj[i]) {
            if (obj[i][j] == true) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var test = {"colors":{"blue":false}, "sizes":{"square":false}}; 
console.log(checkFalse(test)); // for this you will get false since you do not have true in it.

var test = {"colors":{"blue":false}, "sizes":{"square":true}}; 
console.log(checkFalse(test)); // for this you will get true since you   have a true in it.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```js
var test = {"colors":{"blue":false}, "sizes":{"square":true}};
var res = [];
for(var key in test){
  res = Object.keys(test[key]).filter(function(k){
    return test[key][k] == true
  });
}

console.log(res)
```